# How to reduce blank space in html?

Tags: html, css, html-table, adsense

My desired output is:

[image]

My de facto output has too much blank space:

[image]

The code is:

```
<div id="tabarea"><ul id="tabnav"><li class="tab_all"><strong>All</strong></li><li class="tab_private"><a title="Display only info from privates" href="?t=&f=p" >Private<span class="tab_right_links"></span></a></li><li class="tab_company"><a title="Show only info from companies" href="?t=&f=c" >Company<span class="tab_right_links"></span></a></li></ul></div><table><tr><td><table class="listingWithImages" border="0px"><tr><td>4 hours, 3 minutes</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/8oUwXdeweiQmEq_ESy33RQ===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/105">Test2</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYaQw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 hours, 14 minutes</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/HmoH2SsmUcoPOKiJZM-gVw===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/102">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYZgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 hours, 15 minutes</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/zrBsUrSO6T_g48xvf_3GDQ===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/100">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYZAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 hours, 16 minutes</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/mTQP6dGy9OJqChqujxL6PA===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/98">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYYgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 hours, 17 minutes</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/KVMHyBo32fWE_ruH8a7zjQ===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/96">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYYAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 hours, 19 minutes</td><td></td><td><a href="/94/test">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYXgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 hours, 22 minutes</td><td><img src="/images/93.png" alt="Test"/></td><td><a href="/90/test">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYWgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 days, 15 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/72/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYSAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/68/test">Test</a><br/>

EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYRAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/67/test">Test</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYQww" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>4 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/64/test">Test</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYQAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 17 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/63/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>

EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYPww" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 18 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/57/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYOQw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 20 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/52/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYNAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 21 hours</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/hFT-PUQJfOX1jh_P5Zl80A===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/50">Computer services</a><br/>

EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYMgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline"></span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 22 hours</td><td><img src="http://localhost:8080/_ah/img/SnoEEZiYDBbWNauTqvKhTg===s100"></td><td><a href="/servead/46">Computer services</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYLgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline"></span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/42/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYKgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/40/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220

</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYKAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/39/frankwin-international-educatoin-and-immigration">Frankwin International, Educatoin and Immigration</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYJww" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>5 days, 22 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/36/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>
EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYJAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>6 days, 2 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/34/"></a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYIgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>6 days, 3 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/33/"></a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYIQw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>6 days, 3 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/29/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYHQw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>6 days, 3 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/28/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYHAw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>6 days, 3 hours</td><td></td><td><a href="/25/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYGQw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1 week</td><td></td><td><a href="/22/test">Test</a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYFgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1 week</td><td></td><td><a href="/21/"></a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYFQw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1 week</td><td></td><td><a href="/18/"></a><br/></td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYEgw" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1 week, 6 days</td><td><img src="/images/6.png" alt="Computer ..."/></td><td><a href="/3/computer-services">Computer services</a><br/>

EUR&nbsp;220
</td><td><span id="ahFjbGFzc2lmaWVkc21hcmtldHIICxICQWQYAww" style="margin:0; padding:0 display:inline">Sweden</span></td><td></td></tr></table></td><td><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7211665888260307";
/* rektanglar i lista */
google_ad_slot = "7024728308";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//--></script><script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script><br><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7211665888260307";
/* rektanglar i lista */
google_ad_slot = "7024728308";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
//--></script><script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script></td></tr></table></div>
```

Can you see how I should do to reduce to blank space I get? Thank you

EDIT: Inserting a `<br>` into the code at a place makes the gap smaller:
[image]

I think that the gap of the first `<tr>` level above shouldn't be there.

I've uploaded the code to a hosting: [www.montao.com.br/li](http://www.montao.com.br/li)

Comment: Use Firebug, find the source of the spacing, fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Firebug says it's a td element that I can't manipulate other than `valign=top`which doesn't solve it

Comment: That `td` has contents/child nodes. Those nodes have CSS attributes: what are they? What happens when you start changing their margins and padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't read that terrible mess you pasted, but I think its really simple. You are probably using tables for layout. And it looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><!-- here are your images (elements.. list.. whatever) --></td>
    <td><!-- ads are here --></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That cell containing ads is stretched (so ads can fit in) and it stretches also other cells in row.

Solution? Move ads outside of your content table :)

Comment: Thanks but moving ads outside content table still doesn't solve it. It becomes blank space nevertheless.

Comment: If it's possible, upload it to some online hosting (there are many free solutions if you need just html or php/mysql. Then we can see more. OR you can clean your provided code. I am sorry but it's really hard for me to work with what you have posted :)

Comment: Thanks for discussing. I uploaded it here http://www.montao.com.br/li where you can see it's not perfect. I have put in a `<br>` to enable the ads. Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: Great. Now.. where exactly is problem at that page? I can't see that big gap. I tried it in IE9 and FF4

Comment: Great if you don't see the big gap. But there is a gap from adding the `<br>`that I did to remove the larger gap...

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it. Can you please put it back to that big gap version? So we can see what was the problem?

Comment: I solved it by saving the document to disk and refactoring. The layout bug does not appear anymore. It is working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your content in a div

```
<div id="content" >Your content Here</div>
```

and give it a negative margin like so:

```
#content{
margin: - 100px;
}
```

or you could try and delete your page and design it in a different way.

**EDIT:**

another solution would be to wrap the ads in a div and the content and float the beside each other:

```
#content , #ads{
float: left;
}
```

make sure you expand your **main** content box a bit otherwise it won't work.

**EDIT 2:**

use a table tag instead.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td height="600" width="600">CONTENT</td>
<td height="600"  width="200">SIDEBAR</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

this code wouldn't show ANYTHING until everything inside the table is fully loaded

hence i recommend using css, it's good for you.

:)

Comment: +1 for solving the problem but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't need css

Comment: well you could try to restructure your design but maybe your ads are too big and are blocking the box to "slot in"

Comment: you could always use one of those HORRIBLE <table> tags , that would certainly solve your problem